# Twig interpolate variable into translated string

Tags: symfony, twig, translation, sylius

I have a **Sylius** instance with translations file configured and properly working

Right now just using a snippet like this in my `twig`:

```
{{ 'project.sylius.frontend.header.label'|trans }}
```

It retrieves the proper string from the `yaml` translation file:

```
project.sylius.frontend.header.title: Welcome here
```

What I want to know is, if there is the chance to store the strings with interpolation marks straight in the `yaml`, 
something like this:

```
project.sylius.frontend.cart_number: you are going to buy %n candies
project.sylius.frontend.delivery: delivery will be between the %whatever and %whatever
```

And how to pass the variable in the the `twig` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variable to the trans filter as first argument as array,  as Example:

<kbd>yaml</kbd>:

```
project.sylius.frontend.cart_number: you are going to buy %number% candies
```

<kbd>Twig</kbd>:

```
{{ 'project.sylius.frontend.cart_number '|trans({'%number%': '4'}) }}
```

Take a look at the [pluralization features](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates).

Hope this help